# First non-unique beta decay transition (parity of the nucleus is changes)

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, parity

What is the difference in the cross-section of the allowed and 1st non-unique forbidden beta decay transition?

In other words, how does the change in parity of the daughter nucleus influence the cross-section of the beta decay?

From the experimental data, one can see that the half-lifetimes for these 2 transitions are of the same order, so one can assume that it does not depend on the parity, but how to understand it theoretically?

The examples for such a decay are Sm^151, Tm^271.

Thank you.

Comment: I'll presume you mean $^{171}$Tm? Half life of $^{171}$ Tm is 1.92 years, half life of $^{151}$Sm is 90 years.

Comment: Dear Jon, thanks for your answer, but I am interested in the formula for the cross section, not the integrated lifetime

Comment: As a comment (not an answer), it points out a typo in your question, as well as noting that the half lives are different by a factor of 50.